# On Selection of Radio Button the form should appear without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

Hi I am an amateur programmer. I want to have the form appear dynamically without reloading the page once user clicks the radio button. Is there any reference I can find. Can someone help me with this please.

Here's the HTML code

```
<p>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" size="15" maxlength="20"/> </p>

<p>Term <select name="term">
    <option value="noterm">No Term</option>
    <option value="1year">1 Year</option>

</select></p>

<p>Enter IMEI: <input type="text" name="imei" size="15" maxlength="20" value=""/> </p>
<p>Selling Price: <input type="text" name="sprice" size="15" maxlength="20" value=""/> </p>
<p>Rep: <input type="text" name="rep" size="5" maxlength="3" value=""/> </p>
<p><input type="submit"name="submit" value="Tender" /></p>


</form>
<!--This is where I need the action to HAPPEN-->
<form>
<input type="radio" name="Credit" value="ISC" /> ISC<br />
<input type="text" name="credit1" size="15" maxlength="10" value=""/>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't really follow what you mean... which form should appear, and when?

Comment: @james I need the credit1 input to appear at the bottom of the code when user select radio button above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way will be to give your `radio` input and the hidden `text` input an `id`, and then use the following JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("Credit").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("credit1").style.display = "block";
}
```

You will need to hide the text `input` initially, which you can do from in your CSS with `display:none`. You can see an example of that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mpvsz/1/).

If you are able to use jQuery it will be even easier, without adding an `id` to your `input` elements, assuming your `name` attributes are unique:

```
$("input[name=Credit]").click(function() {
    $("input[name=credit1]").show();
});
```

Comment: You should use script to hide the elements so that if javascript is not availble or disabled then the form is still usable. An ID is not required if the element has a name, e.g. `var input = document.forms[9].credit;`. The default value for the input's display property may not be block (in Firefox it's *inline*), to make it visible, set it to "" (empty string) to it adopts the appropriate default or inherited value.